# how to find the number of conjugate?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find the number of conjugates of $(1, 2) (3, 4)$ in  $S_ n , n \ge 4.$

## My attempts :

let $\sigma=(1, 2) (3, 4)$ the conjugate class  of $\sigma$ is
$C(\sigma)$ = { $\tau(12)(34) \tau^{-1}  ,\tau \in S_n$}

$C(\sigma)$={$\tau(1)\tau(2)\tau(3)\tau(4): \tau \in S_n$}

we  observe that  the first element in $\sigma$ can be chosen in $n$ ways , second element in $ (n-1)$ , third element  in $(n-2)$ and the fourth element  in $(n-3)$ ways. so $\sigma $  can be  chosen  in $n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)$ ways.

after that i can not able  to procedd Further  pliz help me...

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us say two elements $a,b\in G$ are conjugate if there exists $c\in G$ such that $a=c^{-1}bc$. The conjugate is an equivalent relation on $G$ and hence $G$ is partitioned into conjugate classes.

$$g(1\mbox{ }2......\mbox{ }t)g^{-1}=(g(1)\mbox{ }\mbox{ }g(2)\mbox{ }...\mbox{ }\mbox{ }\mbox{ }g(t)),\forall g\in S_n$$
$$a(1\mbox{ }\mbox{ }2)(3\mbox{ }\mbox{ }4)a^{-1}=(a(1)\mbox{ }\mbox{ }a(2))\mbox{ }(\mbox{ }a(3)\mbox{ }\mbox{ }a(4))$$
$$a(1)\mbox{ },a(2)\mbox{ },a(3)\mbox{ },a(4)\mbox{ }\in\{1,2,....,n\},\mbox{ and they are distinct}.$$
$$\implies\mbox{there are }n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)\mbox{ ways for choosing }a(1),a(2),a(3),a(4)$$$$\mbox{But }a(1)\mbox{ }\mbox{ }a(2)\mbox{ can be exchange, also }a(3)\mbox{ }\mbox{ }a(4)\mbox{ can}$$$$\mbox{Similarly, }(a(1)\mbox{ }\mbox{ }a(2)),\mbox{ }\mbox{ }(a(3)\mbox{ }\mbox{ }a(4))\mbox{ can be exchange}$$$$\mbox{ Hence, there are }\dfrac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{2\times2\times2}\mbox{ conjugates}$$

Comment: thanks @key Flex,,,,but im not getting   why  u  write  $2 \times 2 \times 2  $   as   how  it come ??

Comment: @stupid Because there are three $2-2$ cycles

Comment: ...can u  write  that  cycle  as  im   getting only  2 , 2-2 cycle  that is  (12)(34), (34)(12), ,

Comment: @stupid Yes, you can